# Why does vim ex mode 'print' command insert a space on empty lines?

Tags: ex-mode

Take the following example:

```
$ printf "a\n\nb\n" | vim -E -c "%p" -c 'q!' /dev/stdin | hexdump -C
00000000  61 0a 20 0a 62 0a                                 |a. .b.|
00000006
```

I would not expect that space (`0x20`) to be present between the two line feeds. I realize I can work around it by writing to `/dev/stdout` instead:

```
$ printf "a\n\nb\n" | vim -E -c "w! /dev/stdout" -c 'q!' /dev/stdin | hexdump -C
00000000  61 0a 0a 62 0a                                    |a..b.|
00000005
```

but I would like to understand what is going on. I searched the vim man page, `:help ex-cmd-index` and also the POSIX man page on ex without finding any explanation why the `print` command behaves this way. I'm observing this on Linux, tested vim version 8.0.1453 and 8.2.814.

Thanks!

Comment: The `:p` (or `:print`) command also expands tabs to spaces... Yeah it's annoying. I've been considering sending a patch to implement a `:print raw` that keeps everything verbatim.

Comment: @filbranden Why mention tab? There has no tab.

Comment: @dedowsdi I was just saying that's another place where I observed the behavior of `:p` mucking with output...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Funny story: I'm writing a script which detects overlong lines in git commit messages, then suggests a word-wrapped version. This is displayed by a git GUI which annoyingly drops empty lines, but luckily not the single spaces. Then git comes along and strips trailing whitespaces by default in a commit. In the end everything works out, but I hate to depend on undocumented behavior in this way... Why can't just everyone leave my stream alone?

Comment: Git’s whitespace behavior is actually well-documented, and vim’s help mentions that print uses things like list and listchars, but there is definitely something to be desired here. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stripspace

Comment: Yes I know that was a bit overdramatic. Git is not to blame because it is documented and configurable, not so much for the other two components.